# Not getting notification in Android Oreo when the app is not running

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am developing an app in which I am not getting notification when the app is not running in Android Oreo. When a push notification is received, the onMessageReceived method is getting called, but the notification is not showing in the notification bar. Whereas if the app is running (foreground or background) I get a notification in notification bar.    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ApplyAndInitiateMainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "100";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.image_new)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setWhen(remoteMessage.getSentTime())
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .addAction(0,"Apply LEAVE",pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap).setSummaryText(message).bigLargeIcon(null));

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

}

Comment: You have to send your unique id as the first argument in the notify() method like this
notificationManager.notify(channelId,notificationBuilder.build());

Comment: @AbhishekSharma it is not taking channelId as the first argument as channelID is string and int is required at that place.

Comment: Okay I thought that is your unique id . You have to generate one unique id to pass as the first argument

Comment: You can create unique id like this :-
uniqueId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Answer (score 0):

Create your notification channel before creating notification:

```
String channelId = "100";
// Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setSmallIcon(R.image_new)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(remoteMessage.getSentTime())
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(0,"Apply LEAVE",pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap).setSummaryText(message).bigLargeIcon(null));
```

Comment: I tried this, but now also I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked if your `onMessageReceived`  gets called at all or the problem is just the notification not getting notified? Cause it seems your code is alright.